# Code flow for consuming Amazon SQS job

Tags: php, amazon-sqs

I am writing worker which consumes job from Amazon SQS, so the code flow is as follow

// symfony

```
while (true) {
    try {
        $jobData = $this->legacyQueue
            ->setQueueName($this->queueName)
            ->receiveMessage();
        $jobDataArray = json_decode($jobData, true);
        $variableArray = array(1,2,3);
        ... // job processing 
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make consuming Amazon SQS job async, the problem with current flow is, the memory allocated for variables inside while loop is not getting freed after processing job. This is causing memory problem on server side.